# Store which Image is being used

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I am thinking how to store the image which is being used in an image texture node

```
 bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image
```

I want to store the image used, and then on clicking a button, that image stored will be applied to some other active object's image texture node

I tried using StringProperty but that stores only String type and not images!

I don't get know how to do that......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your StringProperty to save the `image.name`, 
then load it by accessing the image through `bpy.data.images`:

```
imageNameStringProp = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image.name

someOtherObject.active_material.node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image = bpy.data.images[ imageNameStringProp ]
```